# Python regexp replace text inside tags

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying replace a block of text inside of tags with python sub.

Block of text:

```
text = """##startBlablaTag##
          blablabla
          blebleble
          bliblibli
          ##endtBlablaTag##
```

Using the following regexp with "search" I can catch what's inside of the tags

```
>>> re.search(r'^##\w+Blabla\w+##\n(.*)##\w+Blabla\w+##', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL).group(1)
'blablabla\blebleble\bliblibli\n'
>>>
```

but when I try with "sub" to replace, I can't replace the whole content, just the end...

```
>>> re.sub(r'^##\w+Blabla\w+##\n(.*)##\w+Blabla\w+##', r'\g<1>test!', text, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
'blablabla\nblebleble\nbliblibli\ntest!'

Expected:

##startBlablaTag##
test!
##endtBlablaTag##
```

Anybody knows how to replace the whole content inside the tags?

Thanks!

Comment: @Aran-Fey sorry, post edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it backwards.

The regex you used is this:

```
^##\w+Blabla\w+##\n(.*)##\w+Blabla\w+##
```

As you can see, you have used a capture group to capture the text inside of the tag. In other words, you've captured the text that you want to remove. This serves no purpose - you should be using capture groups around the text that you want to *keep*. In other words, the regex should look like this:

```
^(##\w+Blabla\w+##\n).*(##\w+Blabla\w+##)
```

Now you can use backreferences to refer to the captured text during the substitution and insert new text inside of the tags:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^(##\w+Blabla\w+##\n).*(##\w+Blabla\w+##)', r'\1test!\2', text, flags=re.S)
'##startBlablaTag##\ntest!##endtBlablaTag##'
```